# jquery fancybox for magento 2

Tags: magento2, jquery, requirejs

Its working in my localhost, but when use same code in magento 2 its not working any suggestions please

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>fancyBox - Fancy jQuery Lightbox Alternative | Demonstration</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <!-- Add jQuery library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>  
    <!-- Add fancyBox main JS and CSS files -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.fancybox').fancybox();

        });
    </script>
</head>
<li><a class="fancybox fancybox.ajax" href="terms-of-use">Ajax</a></li>
```

Comment: have you check your fancybox.js is loaded or not in site?

Comment: check your browser console !!! you can see error there might be js is not loading

Comment: @Rakesh yes its loading fancy box as well but content not showing in popup

Comment: @ Manthan its not showing any error

Comment: Hi Friends, solved this  $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        type: "iframe"
    });

Answer (score 5):

JS should be loaded through Require JS and not added inline like that. This is how I recommend adding it:

**Require JS config**

```
File: app/design/frontend/Store/theme/requirejs-config.js

var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            fancybox: 'js/vendor/fancybox3/jquery.fancybox.min',
        }
    }
};
```

**Your JS**

I have left out my unrelated code

```
require(['jquery', 'fancybox', 'domReady!'], function($, fancybox, doc) {
    var fancyboxExample = {

        ...

        openModal: function() {
            $.fancybox.open(this.$modal);
        },

        closeModal: function() {
            $.fancybox.close(true);
        }

        ...

    };

    // Initialise
    fancyboxExample.init();
});
```

**Alternative global method**

Another method is to load this on every page by adding this to your Require JS config:

```
deps: [
    'fancybox'
]
```

And then you can simply add the attributes to your markup like this:

```
<a href="image.jpg" data-fancybox>
    <img src="thumbnail.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
```

^^ That is for Fancybox 3.

Comment: Note that using `domReady!` is better practice than `$(document).ready` when using Require JS as any modules that depend on this will be aware of the dom ready requirement.

Comment: and if we cannot find less file we can add fanybox css via head  layout <css src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.7/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.css" src_type="url" />   I had problem adding this by import in less file.

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Add the script to your theme.

**THEME\web\js\jquery\3.5.7.fancybox.min.js**

```
!function(t,e,n,o){"use strict";function i(t,e){var o,i,a,s=[],r=0;t&&t.isDefaultPrevented()||...
```

You can find it [here](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/).

#### 1.1 Add script to requirejs-config.js file

**THEME\requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        fancybox: 'js/jquery/3.5.7.fancybox.min'
    }
};
```

### 3. Add CSS to your layout

In my case I add it to *catalog_product_view* because I only need flexbox for products.

**THEME\Magento_Catalog\layout\catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.7/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.css" src_type="url" order="10"/>
    </head>
    <body>
         ...
```

### 4. Add your flex images to the CMS site or product CMS.

```
<a href="/foo.jpg" target="_blank" class="fancybox">
    <img class="img-thumbnail" src="{{media url='/foo.jpg'}}" alt="foo">
</a>
<a href="/bar.jpg" target="_blank" class="fancybox">
    <img class="img-thumbnail" src="{{media url='/bar.jpg'}}" alt="bar">
</a>
```

### 5. Add the script into the CMS:

```
<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'fancybox',
        'domReady!'
    ], function ($, fancybox) {

        $('.fancybox').fancybox({
              buttons : [ 
                'slideShow',
                'share',
                'zoom',
                'fullScreen',
                'close'
              ],
              thumbs : {
                autoStart : true
              }
        });
    });
</script>
```

### 6. Flush cache

### 7. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I have done exactly as described by Ben Crook, but I'm getting some errors.

[image]

Can't I load the following js in a custom js file?

Loaded through `default_head_blocks.xml` with `<link src="js/custom.js"/>`?

```
require(['jquery', 'fancybox', 'domReady!'], function($, fancybox, doc) {
var fancyboxExample = {
    openModal: function() {
        $.fancybox.open(this.$modal);
    },

    closeModal: function() {
        $.fancybox.close(true);
    }

};

// Initialise
fancyboxExample.init();
});
```

Thanks,

Answer (score -1):

Use full URL in your `href`

```
<?php
$url = $block->getUrl('terms-of-use');
?>
<a class="fancybox fancybox.ajax" href="<?php echo $url ?>">Ajax</a>
```

Comment: Do not recommend people to use the Object Manager and definitely not in PHTML templates.

Comment: @JisseReitsma, Thank you for the suggestion. Updated the answer.

Answer (score -1):

**Now try this code.**

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery('.fancybox').fancybox();

        });
      </script>

      <a class="fancybox fancybox.ajax" href="<?php echo $url ?>">Ajax</a>
```

Comment: Do not recommend people to skip the usage of RequireJS, because jQuery is loaded via RequireJS so therefore, any dependency of jQuery needs to be loaded via RequireJS as well.