# Magento 2.3 and FancyBox doesn't work :-(

Tags: magento2, theme

I need to add this to Magento 2

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.6/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.6/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
```

To be able to use fancybox on CMS pages

```
<a data-fancybox="gallery" href="big_1.jpg"><img src="small_1.jpg"></a>
<a data-fancybox="gallery" href="big_2.jpg"><img src="small_2.jpg"></a>
```

But either it:

- breaks the Ultimo Theme and works

or

- not breaks the Ultimo Theme and doesn't work

I have tried several ways to do this in the theme `default.xml` and or theme `default_head_blocks.xml`

Can someone please shed some light on this?
Thanks,

**---UPDATE---**

I have tested the solution in the link provided below, and it does not work.

After adding requirejs-config.js to the theme root, the following lines are loaded:

```
<script  type="text/javascript"  src="http://domain.xyz/pub/static/version1549118304/frontend/Infortis/ultimo/sv_SE/requirejs/require.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript"  src="http://domain.xyz/pub/static/version1549118304/frontend/Infortis/ultimo/sv_SE/mage/requirejs/mixins.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript"  src="http://domain.xyz/pub/static/version1549118304/frontend/Infortis/ultimo/sv_SE/requirejs-config.js"></script>
```

I have also set `data-fancybox` to all links.
Still doesn't work.

Where should I put the following code?

```
require(['jquery', 'fancybox', 'domReady!'], function($, fancybox, doc) {
var fancyboxExample = {
    openModal: function() {
        $.fancybox.open(this.$modal);
    },

    closeModal: function() {
        $.fancybox.close(true);
    }
};

// Initialise
fancyboxExample.init();
});
```

Comment: jQuery is already included in Magento, and you have to use `requireJS` to add new scripts. Here's how https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/158894/jquery-fancybox-for-magento-2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery fancybox for magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/158894/jquery-fancybox-for-magento-2)

Comment: Thank's, I'll try that, please let me get back with the results.

Comment: Doesn't work. What does "Your JS" mean, is that a custom JS that needs to be loaded?

require(['jquery', 'fancybox', 'domReady!'], function($, fancybox, doc) {
    var fancyboxExample = {

        openModal: function() {
            $.fancybox.open(this.$modal);
        },

        closeModal: function() {
            $.fancybox.close(true);
        }

   
    };

    // Initialise
    fancyboxExample.init();
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, just needed to add the `.css` :-)

This solution works:
[jquery fancybox for magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/158894/jquery-fancybox-for-magento-2)